# the response is coming null in curl

Tags: php, curl

the response is coming as NULL .Here is my code:

```
$url = "http://www.localhost:81/dbWIP/selectApi.php?name='$name'";
$client = curl_init();
echo $client;
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$response = curl_exec($client);
curl_close($client);
$result = json_decode($response);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Any errors on your page? Did you set error_reporting to 1?

Comment: I suspect `?name='$name'"` is the cause. But also why are you echoing `$client`, you should be using [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and echoing out `$response` before json_decoding it.. reason its null is json_decode failed as its not json for *some* reason. Also enable error reporting, curl might not be installed ;p

Comment: try this `$url = "http://www.localhost:81/dbWIP/selectApi.php?name=".$name;`

Comment: Did the URL you give to curl output something?

Comment: and [echo json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) will tell you what went wrong

Comment: now the error occcured is:Curl error: Could not resolve host: www.localhost

Answer (score 1):

The $name var isn't properly showing try this:

```
$url = "http://www.localhost:81/dbWIP/selectApi.php?name=".$name;
```

Right now it is just showing:

> $url = "http://www.localhost:81/dbWIP/selectApi.php?name='$name'";